# Database error: Lookup type 'in' can't be negated

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-queryset

I am using Django framework, appengine database.

My code for model is:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ispublic = models.BooleanField()
    logo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    groupwebsite = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('profile')


class Group_members(models.Model):
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    group = models.ForeignKey('group')
```

I am querying on `Group_members` to remove group. My query is as follows:

```
groups = Group_members.objects.filter(Q(profile=profile.id),~Q(group__in=group_id)
```

INFO:

1. `group_id = ['128','52']`
2. `group` is a foreign key to group model

My problem is when I run this query, it throws Database error: `Lookup type 'in' can't be negated`.

I have also performed query using `__in` it worked fine but does not work for foreign key.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using the HRD datastore?  The datastore can't handle NOT IN queries.

Comment: Nope m not using HRD datastore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you trying to filter profile id and remove groups in group_id in single filter

```
groups = Group_members.objects.filter(Q(profile=profile.id),~Q(group__in=group_id)
```

instead try this:

1)first filter the profiles form group_member :

```
groups = Group_members.objects.filter(profile=profile.id)
```

2)remove the groups form Queryset by:

```
groupId = [x.group.id for x in groups if x.group.id not in group_id]
```

Hope this will give you perfect result

Comment: Wooow,thats a great idea, u rock,n thanks that works perfect...u r Genius buddy..+1 for this

Answer (score 1):

2 suggestions.

1. Use ~Q(group__ pk__in=group_id)
2. Instead of using **filter** and not in, use **exclude** and in